# CSS Gallery not responding

Tags: css

My CSS Gallery specifications are not corresponding to my HTML5. The images are not following the hover tag and they are displaying on top of everything else. It will not stay fixed however when I change the positioning to `fixed` it disappear all together. CSS checker states validates all fine. I can not position it where I want on the page either. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

**CSS CODE**

```
#gallery {

bottom: -20px;
padding-right: 50px; 
display: inline;
top: 200px;
z-index: 99999999;
}

#gallery ul {
list-style-type: none;
padding: 20px;
text-align: center;
position: fixed;


}

#gallery li {
display: inline;
padding-right: 20px;

}

#gallery img {
padding: 5px 5px 40px 5px;
background: white;
box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px -4px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px -4px #000000;
-mox-box-shadow:4px 4px 8px -4px #000000;
}


#gallery:hover {


-webkit-transform:scale(5%);
-o-transform:scale(5%);
-moz-transform:scale(5%);
-ms-transform: scale(5%);
transform: scale(5%);

transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition:0.5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition:0.5s ease-in-out;
-mox-transition:0.5s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Could you please put all markup and styles into a jsFiddle?

Comment: Sorry I am new to html and css. What is a jsfiddle?

Comment: jsfiddle.net - Create your page there.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. it is still displaying the same way

Comment: @Hayley the idea is that you share with people here the URL of the jsfiddle test you've created.